# Do we have any API available for Avature?

Tags: sharepoint, download

I am looking for the APIs available to fetch data from [Avature](https://www.avature.net/) and I am not able to find any documentation on their site.

Do we have any APIs available to get data from Avature?

My goal is to fetch documents from Avature and store them in SharePoint.

Comment: I'm facing the same question now. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

same problem, cant find anything. It seems like all docs are "personalized" and available only from admin panel

> Personalized Automatic Documentation Endpoints self-document via an
> industry-standard Swagger format and contain built-in testing
> features, better positioning third parties to make the right
> connection quickly and easily.

https://www.avature.net/avature-integrations/
[image]